# Good Practice: To Modify Only Function Parameters?

Tags: c++

Say, I develop a complex application: Within object member functions, should I modify only those objects, that are passed to the member functions as parameters, or can I access and modify any other objects I have access to(say public or static objects)?

Technically, I know that it is possible to modify anything I have access to. I am asking about **good practices**.

Sometimes, it is bothering to pass as an argument everythying i will access and modify, especially if I know that the object member function will not be used by anybody else, but me. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Global state is never a good idea (though it is sometimes simpler, for example logging), because it introduces dependencies that are not documented in the interface and increase coupling between components. Therefore, modifying a global state (`static` variables for example) should be avoided at all costs. *Note: global constants are perfectly okay*

In C++, you have the `const` keyword, to document (and have the compiler enforce) what can be modified and what cannot.

A `const` method is a guarantee that the visible state of an object will be untouched, an argument passed by `const` reference, or value, will not be touched either.

As long as it is documented, it is fine... and you should strive for having as few non-`const` methods in your class interface and as few non-`const` parameters in your methods.

Comment: I am marking this answer as the *Accepted Answer* as I think it is more detailed one from the two answers given here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a class with member variables, then it is entirely acceptable to modify those member variables in a member method regardless of whether those member variables are private, protected, or public.  This is want is meant by encapsulation.

In fact, modifying the variables passed into the member method is probably a bad idea; returning a new value is what you'd want, or getting a new value back from a separate member method.

Comment: +1 and thank you for your good answer. I will wait few moments until I close this thread.

Comment: @Bunkai: don't feel obligated to close it within 30 minutes or an hour, it's fine to leave it open for a few days, not all people are awake at the moment and you might get better answers / comments if you wait a bit :)

Comment: @Matthieu M.: That was useful point for me. I usually tried to close the thread as soon as possible, ususally within one or two hours. Thanks :-)